# Reading from csv files

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

This is a project i'm working on at college, everything seems good except in the game class which initializes the game.  Here is a snippet

```
public class Game{
 private Player                         player;
 private World                          world;
 private ArrayList<NonPlayableFighter>  weakFoes;
 private ArrayList<NonPlayableFighter>  strongFoes;
 private ArrayList<Attack>              attacks;
 private ArrayList<Dragon>              dragons;

public Game() throws IOException{
    player      = new Player("");
    world       = new World();
    weakFoes    = new ArrayList<NonPlayableFighter>();
    strongFoes  = new ArrayList<NonPlayableFighter>();
    attacks     = new ArrayList<Attack>();
    dragons     = new ArrayList<Dragon>();
    loadAttacks ("Database-Attacks_20309.csv");
    loadFoes    ("Database-Foes_20311.csv");
    loadDragons ("Database-Dragons_20310.csv");
}
```

after that follows some getters and the 4 method i am supposed to implement.
These methods are `loadCSV(String filePath)`,`loadAttacks(String filePath)`,`loadFoes(String filePath)`,`loadDragons(String filePath)`
I have created `loadCSV(String filePath)` such that it returns an ArrayList of String[] here:

```
private ArrayList<String[]> loadCSV(String filePath) throws IOException{
    String currentLine          = ""; 
    ArrayList<String[]> result  = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    FileReader fileReader       = new FileReader(filePath); 
    BufferedReader br           = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 
    currentLine                 = br.readLine();
    while (currentLine != null){ 
        String[] split = currentLine.split(",");
        result.add(split);
    }
    br.close();
    return result;
}
```

Then i would like to load some attacks, foes, and dragons and inserting them in the appropriate ArrayList.
I applied `loadAttacks(String filePath)` here:

```
private void loadAttacks(String filePath) throws IOException{
    ArrayList<String[]> allAttacks = loadCSV(filePath);
    for(int i = 0; i < allAttacks.size(); i++){
        String[] current = allAttacks.get(i);
        Attack temp = null;
        switch(current[0]){
            case "SA": temp = new SuperAttack(current[1], 
                    Integer.parseInt(current[2]));
                    break;
            case "UA": temp = new UltimateAttack(current[1], 
                    Integer.parseInt(current[2]));
                    break;
            case "MC": temp = new MaximumCharge();
                    break;
            case "SS": temp = new SuperSaiyan();
                    break;
        }
        attacks.add(temp);
    }
}
```

I wrote it such that it takes the ArrayList returned from `loadCSV(String filePath)` and searches in each String[] within the ArrayList on the first String using a switch thus creating the appropriate attack and adding it to attacks.
Then i would like to read another CSV for the Foes and the CSV file is structured such that in the first line there are some attributes the second line some attacks of type SuperAttack and the third line holds some attacks of type Ultimate attack. Also within each foe there is a boolean attribute that determines if it is a Strong or Weak Foe thus putting it in the right Arraylist. Here is the code for `loadFoes(String filePath)`:

```
private void loadFoes(String filePath) throws IOException{
    ArrayList<String[]> allFoes = loadCSV(filePath);
    for(int i = 0; i < allFoes.size(); i += 3){
        String[] current                            = allFoes.get(i);
        String[] supers                             = allFoes.get(i+1);
        String[] ultimates                          = allFoes.get(i+2);
        ArrayList<SuperAttack> superAttacks         = new ArrayList<SuperAttack>();
        ArrayList<UltimateAttack> ultimateAttacks   = new ArrayList<UltimateAttack>();
        NonPlayableFighter temp = null;
        for(int j = 0; i < supers.length; j++){
            int index = attacks.indexOf(supers[j]);
            if(index != -1){
                superAttacks.add((SuperAttack)attacks.get(index));
            }
            else break;
        }
        for(int j = 0; i < ultimates.length; j++){
            int index = attacks.indexOf(ultimates[j]);
            if(index != -1){
                ultimateAttacks.add((UltimateAttack)attacks.get(index));
            }
            else break;
        }
        if(current[7].equalsIgnoreCase("True")){
            temp = new NonPlayableFighter(current[0], Integer.parseInt(current[1]), 
                            Integer.parseInt(current[2]), Integer.parseInt(current[3]), 
                            Integer.parseInt(current[4]), Integer.parseInt(current[5]), 
                            Integer.parseInt(current[6]), true, superAttacks, ultimateAttacks);

            strongFoes.add(temp);
        }
        else{
            temp = new NonPlayableFighter(current[0], Integer.parseInt(current[1]), 
                            Integer.parseInt(current[2]), Integer.parseInt(current[3]), 
                            Integer.parseInt(current[4]), Integer.parseInt(current[5]), 
                            Integer.parseInt(current[6]), false, superAttacks, ultimateAttacks);

            weakFoes.add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

First i get the first three String[] in the ArrayList returned from `loadCSV(String filePath` and made 2 loops to check if the attacks are within the previously loaded attacks CSV then i check for the attribute that determines if it is a strong or weak and accordingly creating a new `NonPlayableFighter` and adding it to the appropriate list.

Running the jUnit4 tests for this assignment it gives me a Compilation Error: Unhandled exception type IOException. And generally speaking does the code have any notable problems ?

Comment: Did you handle Exception (using try/catch or throws ) in Main Class or in main() ?

Comment: into loadCSV() method, add  currentLine   = br.readLine(); into while loop too.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to reuse already exist CSV file readers for Java (e.g. [CVSReader](http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv_samples.php)) if isn't a part of you task.

Comment: It is a task to create the loadCSV method

Comment: @alimoenes I see... In this case I'd rather make `BufferedReader` as a parameter of your `loacCSV` method. It'll make your method more universal: you'll can read CSV data from any source (file, memory, network...). Also you must add another `readLine` call inside you reading data loop for reading not only the first CSV line.

Comment: i can't understand the part about the bufferedreader. i will try putting the readline in the loop and give you feedback. Thank you

Comment: @alimoenes it's even better to change: from your `loadCSV(String filePath)` to `loadCSV(Reader reader)`. After this change you can call your method both `loadCSV(new FileReader("Database-Attacks_20309.csv"))` and `loadCSV(new StringReader(...string constant in memory...))` (it's good e.g. for testing your method) and `loadCSV(new URLReader(new URL("http://...")))` (for reading from network). This will make your `loadCSV` independent from data source (file, string, network...) and more flexible in usage.

Answer (score 0):

That makes a lot of code. I'll answer to your Compilation Error.

While reading a file you have to pu your code in a try catch in order to avoid this kind of error. In your loadCSV method you have to set up a try catch block.

Please refer to [this site](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) for complete tutorial.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt")))
    {

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] split = currentLine.split(",");
            result.add(split);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To make it short, code that access to files have to be in a try catch to avoid IO Exception, or be in a method that throws the exception (but then it has to be catched elsewhere).

In that code you have a good example of a try-with-resource, very good way to manage your ressource and memory.

Comment: Thank you, we haven't taken using exceptions yet and this milestone was intended to work without using try, catch, throw and so on we were given an example on how to build a csv reader and we were supposed to determine a return type and adjust it.

Comment: This kind of consideration doesn't apply to the language ^^ Everything is available to the language. But is you want to avoid using try-catch (i advice you to give it a try anyway :p), you must be sure that your main method has `throws IOException` . Every method of the stack should have it to let the exception go.

Answer (score 0):

loadCSV(String filePath) is a infinite loop isn't it? And as for the IOException it as @RPresle suggested a try/catch would do the trick around the BufferedReader.